# use function calls in Angular template

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 8 and i want to use function with paramaters calls in Angular template so i used the PipeTransform 
the problem is the variable is undefined outside of subscribe when i use service

this is the CqpPipe.pipe.ts

```
 projectCqp :string[];
 transform(value: number, args?: any) {

    this.cqpservice.getNumberOfProjectPerCQP(value, "Ressource Allocation").subscribe(data  => {
    this.projectCqp = data;});}
```

and this is the service

```
  getNumberOfProjectPerCQP(cqpid:number,type:string){
return this.httpclient.get<string[]>(this.cqpUrl+'/project/CqpAndType/'+cqpid+'/' + type);}
```

and finally i called the function in a table that way:  {{c.id | getNumberOfProject }} which is return nothing in the template

Comment: Hi, this is an async problem. You should read more about how to use `Observables` inside pipes.

Answer (score 1):

so the main problem I see there is, that you have to stop using a subscription in the pipe, just map the Observable and use the async pipe in template to resolve value.

Look on this:

```
transform(value: number, args?: any) {
    return this.cqpservice.getNumberOfProjectPerCQP(value, "Ressource Allocation").pipe(map(data  => data));
}
```

of course, this map is redundant - you can omit that, but if you want to change anything just use the map.

then in the template:

```
<div>{{data | cqpPipe | async}}</div>
```

Comment: the same probleme,nothing is displayed.